# LinuxのApache上で動作しているmod_phpでシステムツールを使ったボトルネックを探す方法

Tags: php

PHPを使ったアプリケーションを運用している時に、アプリケーションコードの
デプロイなどの外的な要因に突然負荷が上がる事があります。

その際に

- コードの変更を加えない
- Apacheの設定に変更を加えない
- パッケージをインストールすることは有りとする

という条件の場合に一般的なシステムツール等を使ってボトルネックとなっているPHPのページを見つける手段はどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

ぱっと思いつくのは、httpdのプロセスIDを全部調べて、

```
$ strace -o /tmp/out.txt -r -p [pid1] -p [pid2] -p [pid3] ...
```

などとしておいて、不整脈が出たら停止、/tmp/out.txtをあさって、openされているファイルに軸をあわせて時間がかかっている箇所を特定する、とかでしょうか？

Comment: straceは定番ですねー。他に解答こないかみたいのでちょっとオープンのままにさせて下さい

Answer (score 1):

Dtrace を使うという手がありますが、お使いのディストリビューションによっては難しいかもしれません。

参考)
http://co3k.org/blog/21